# Webpage convert to PDF button

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have a website now and I want to create a button on it to convert this page to PDF.
Is there any code to make this happen? I cannot find it on the internet.

So I want to have a button and when I press on it it converts the page to a .PDF file.

I do not want to use a third party website to generate the PDF's. I want to use it for internal purposes to generate files with PHP. So I need the code what can make a PDF for each page.

Comment: "I cannot find it on the internet." did you google "html to pdf php" <- that will give you some good results

Comment: Thanks ManseUK I will be more carefull about accept answers. I was too fast with that. Indeed all three answers do not work. I tried to Google that, but there isn't any good website I can find. I do not want to use a third party website to generate the PDF's. I want to use it for internal purposes to generate files with PHP. So I need the code what can make a PDF for each page.

Answer (score 5):

I use wkhtmltopdf - works very well - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ there is a PHP wrapper

Updated based on comments below on usage :

How to use the [integration class](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp):

```
require_once('wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.php');     // Ensure this path is correct !
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
$pdf = new WKPDF();
$pdf->set_html($html);
$pdf->render();
$pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED,'sample.pdf');
```

Comment: Is this program only for windows? I cannot find the files. I can download a .exe file. I use mac

Comment: @HansdeVries Im using a mac too, try here -> http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list look for **Mac OSX Static Library**

Comment: I downloaded the static library. But there files are unknown for me. libwkhtmltox.0.10.0.dylib. wkhtmltopdf www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.pdf this part to use it is php code?

Comment: @HansdeVries here is the usage documentation : http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage     here is the PHP integrtation : http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

Comment: Can you please explain me in short steps how to integrade this into for example index.php? I do not understand the documentations. I do update the index.php on my server so not local. Do i need to run the libwkhtmltox.dylib file om my mac? Do I need to copy those files into my html map?

Comment: @HansdeVries the **wkhtmltopdf** is the executable you will need to copy that to wherever you want to run the script from. I have also updated my answer with some PHP code to show you typical usage

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to make this work but I got the error: Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in ... I pasted the PHP code (from this first post) in the index.php. I made a php file with the name wkhtmltopdf.php and putted it in the same folder as my index.php. (ftp). after I open index.php it gives that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). It's a well-respected PDF-generating library for PHP that is written in pure PHP (so installing it should be dead simple for you).

Comment: FPDF - that doesnt do HTML to PDF .... even the FAQ on the website points you to another product !

Comment: With this, is it possible to generate a PDF of an existing page? I have to style the PHP file to create that as PDF. I want to create a PDF of multiple pages. Just what I see on the page to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting_HTML2PDF_using_PHP.asp

It will convert HTML to a PDF using FPDF and HTML2PDF class.

Also found this:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3168-PHP-Generate-PDF-documents-from-HTML-pages.html

Comment: The files of: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3168-PHP-Generate-PDF-documents-from-HTML-pages.html do not work. The domain for what the PHP is referring is sold. So the services do not work anymore.

Comment: Scroll down and you'll find this link
http://www.macronimous.com/resources/html2pdf_sample.zip

In the phpclasses.org class you need to register or login in order to get the files. I got the file.

Comment: Is it possible to create a pdf with an external url instead of local .html files?

Comment: I tried this, but it won't save the images from the .css file. Is it only possible to put images into the sample.html?

Comment: I don't know... Maybe not. It will get the elements of the page. You can create a PDF from a remote URL using PHP's CURL function and get the page first. Them you may print it. Also you can do this using an hidden iFrame, I guess.