# Convert HTML protected page to PDF with nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Im having the exact same issue as the following user but he is using php and im using nodejs. Any solution you can give me? Thank you

[Converting a password protected web page to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943652/converting-a-password-protected-web-page-to-pdf)

Basically im trying to convert a password protected webpage to pdf, so when i use any module to achive this, instead of giving me a pdf with the page content, it gives me a pdf with "please enter password".

Ive tried with html-to-pdf and Puppeteer modules. Both have the same problem. Im trying to do it with JS on the front end, so when the user clicks in "download to pdf" button, it triggers a window.print().

Comment: Maybe you can use Puppeteer or something to do that.

Comment: Ive already tried and it doesnt work.

Comment: Update your post with what you have done so far. Without code snippet, it's hard to understand what's working and what's not