# Print web pages to pdf via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a webpage in pure `HTML` and `CSS`. This page is on localhost. I want to convert this page into `pdf`.
What might be the best approach to convert it into `pdf` preserving all `CSS` styles. 
This may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119481/how-to-convert-web-page-to-pdf), but it would be more convenient to find a solution in `JavaScript`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a pdf from html web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046187/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-html-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are HTML to PDF converters available for free, and you could automatically start a download with that. An example of this would be jsPDF, a free library for converting HTML to a [PDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) with Javascript